# SQL Server - Selecting periods without changes in data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, window-functions

What I am trying to do is to select periods of time where the rest of data in the table was stable based on one column and check was there a change in second column value in this period.

Table:

```
create table #stable_periods
(
[Date]             date,
[Car_Reg]          nvarchar(10),
[Internal_Damages] int,
[External_Damages] int
)

insert into #stable_periods
values  ('2015-08-19', 'ABC123', 10, 10),
        ('2015-08-18', 'ABC123', 9, 10),
        ('2015-08-17', 'ABC123', 8, 9),
        ('2015-08-16', 'ABC123', 9, 9),
        ('2015-08-15', 'ABC123', 10, 10),
        ('2015-08-14', 'ABC123', 10, 10),
        ('2015-08-19', 'ABC456', 5, 3),
        ('2015-08-18', 'ABC456', 5, 4),
        ('2015-08-17', 'ABC456', 8, 4),
        ('2015-08-16', 'ABC456', 9, 4),
        ('2015-08-15', 'ABC456', 10, 10),
        ('2015-01-01', 'ABC123', 1, 1),
        ('2015-01-01', 'ABC456', NULL, NULL);

--select * from #stable_periods
-- Unfortunately I can’t post pictures yet but you get the point of how the table looks like
```

What I would like to receive is

```html
Car_Reg   FromDate ToDate           External_Damages    Have internal damages changed in this period?
ABC123   2015-08-18 2015-08-19   10               Yes
ABC123   2015-08-16 2015-08-17   9               Yes
ABC123   2015-08-14 2015-08-15   10               No
ABC123   2015-01-01 2015-01-01   1               No
ABC456   2015-08-19 2015-08-19   3               No
ABC456   2015-08-16 2015-08-18   4               Yes
ABC456   2015-08-15 2015-08-15   10               No
ABC456   2015-01-01 2015-01-01   NULL               NULL
```

Basically to build period frames where [External_Damages] were constant and check did the [Internal_Damages] change in the same period (doesn't matter how many times).
I spend a lot of time trying but I am afraid that my level of abstraction thinking in much to low...
Will be great to see any suggestions.

Thanks,

Bartosz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is a form of [**Islands Problem**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/71550/).

Here is a solution using `ROW_NUMBER` and `GROUP BY`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/54f9c/1/0)

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *,
        RN = DATEADD(DAY, - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Car_reg, External_Damages ORDER BY [Date]), [Date])
    FROM #stable_periods
)
SELECT
    Car_Reg,
    FromDate = MIN([Date]),
    ToDate = MAX([Date]) ,
    External_Damages,
    Change =
            CASE 
                WHEN MAX(External_Damages) IS NULL THEN NULL
                WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Internal_Damages) > 1 THEN 'Yes' 
                ELSE 'No' 
            END     
FROM CTE c
GROUP BY Car_Reg, External_Damages, RN
ORDER BY Car_Reg, ToDate DESC
```

Comment: Is there any option which could handle missing days in dataset? Assuming that if in surrounding periods [External_Damages] are the same, then they will be the same in those missing days and we can create one longer period instead of few containing breaks caused missing days in data?

Comment: @BartoszX, I suggest you create a new question for that.